# How to select elements in div.parentElement in javascript - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to console.log first image in big div. Big div is selected by parent element.

```
function click(e){
     console.log(e.target.parentElement) //this will selekt bigDiv
     console.log(e.target.parentElement[2]) // like this dont work
     
 }
<div className="bigDiv">
   <div></div>
   <div></div
   <img /> // I want to select this when click div ⬇
   <div onclick={click}>Click me<div/>
   <img />
</div>
```

Comment: `parentElement` is not an array (or like) structure. An element can only have 1 direct parent. You need to access the `children` property of the parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
e.target.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

you can use query selector to select an array of images

```
var nodes = div.querySelectorAll('img');
var first = nodes[0];
var last = nodes[nodes.length- 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the element immediately prior to the clicked element you can just use e.target.previousElementSibling - [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/previousElementSibling)